# El texto del botón no es visible en el emulador de IOS

Tags: angular, ionic, ios, xcode

**Comportamiento actual:**

El texto del botón no aparece. Este comportamiento solo ocurre en iOS, emulador de iPhone y no ocurre en dispositivo físico o Android (físico o simulador).

**Comportamiento esperado:**
el texto del botón debe estar siempre visible.

**Pasos para reproducir:**
Solo necesita agregar un botón de iones en la plantilla.

```html
 <ion-button mode="ios"  expand="full" size="large" shape="round" color="primary" (click)="submit()" >
      <ion-label slot="start"  >Confirmar</ion-label>
 </ion-button>
```

El dispositivo emulador es un **iPhone 8 con iOS 14.1** y se crea desde cero en xcode. En esta captura de pantalla, por ejemplo, el texto sobre el botón en el pie de página no es visible.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: You question is in english, please ask in https://stackoverflow.com or translate your question

Comment: No sé sobre esto, pero quería preguntarte: ¿Que servicio es ese para emular dispositivos?

Comment: @YaelMassieu desde XCode al ejecutar tu app podes seleccionar el dispositivo y emularlo.

Comment: Sucede lo mismo con una versión anterior de iOS 14?